# Retrieve data from database every few seconds?

Tags: c#, database

i need to retrieve data from database every few seconds, display them.

i use C#. When i press one button, the data should be retrieved every few seconds,the data is then displayed in a form, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Half a dozen people told you how. I'll tell you that polling is the single biggest performance pig I've seen. How many client will be doing this? In some systems I work on, I've seen polling eating up 2 CPUs... since it doesn't stop, you've just written off 2 of n cpus, gone... Polling is incessant. Try to find a way to push changes instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to do this, please.. please **read this**:

[Walkthrough: Adding a Local Database Cache to an N-Tier Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882690(v=vs.100).aspx)

As others have mentioned, you can use a [`Timer`](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/02/c-timer-demo/) for this. Remember that you Only want to ask the database for new data when there actually is new data to fetch.

Comment: dead link. sadly. didn't find the new version

Comment: @KahnKah Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a timer in your C# application that will call a stored procedure on your database to retrieve the results into a DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) to periodically execute your query and update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Timer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp11302005054911AM/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a windows forms application?  If so, what you could do is add a timer to the form with a tick time of X seconds, each time it elapses you can query and update the display with the new records.

To start the process you simply start the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Backgroundworker](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) to retrieve data, then use a message to the GUI thread to update in the form

Comment: BackgroundWorker is not needed in this case. It's used for long calculations or tasks, anyway you need to implement timing functionality.

Comment: Yes, I see according to other posts :) Didn't know you could simple update a dataset so the GUI will automaticly update. Good to know :)